# Show the 4 months moving average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. Below you can see a schema. I want to solve the following query.
But the sample solution is different of my solution.

So I have a few questions:

- Why is there an `AVG (AVG(...))`
- Why do I need the `OVER`
- Is there no option to do it like my query?

The schema
[image]

```sql
Write in SQL the following query to the sales schema:
Show the 4 months moving average of sold items per city from 2008 to 2010.
Describe in words what the monthly average of sold items actually means, and what it
means to use this for a 4 months moving average.
```

The sample solution

```sql
SELECT city, month, AVG (numberSold),
AVG (AVG (numberSold)) OVER (ORDER BY month, ROWS 3 PRECEDING)
AS movAvg4months
FROM Sales, Times, Geography
WHERE year BETWEEN 2008 AND 2010
AND Sales.TimeId = Time.TimeId
AND Sales.GeoId = Geography.GeoId
```

My solution

```sql
SELECT city, AVG(numberSold), Quarter
FROM Sales AS s, Time AS t, Geography AS g
WHERE s.GeoID = g.GeoID
AND s.TimeID = t.TimeID
AND YEAR BETWEEN 2008 AND 2010
GROUP BY Quarter;
```

Comment: A sample solution doing implicit, comma separated joins - in 2022?!?  Consider switching to another class.

Comment: *The sample solution* is synthactically errorneous for MySQL, see [Window Function Frame Specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html). The task solved by your solution does not match the task set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the City in the `GROUP BY` in your solution, you will receive the average sold number of the products on the city and the quarter level. So the `AVGs` are calculated **separately** over the quarters. I mean, each sold number data will belong to one row of your result, but you need something else.

The rolling means that a data need to belong to more than 1 row of the result somehow. So it should be considered in other records of the result.

E.g. You have the following data:

| Month | numberSold |
| --- | --- |
| January | 1 |
| February | 2 |
| March | 3 |
| April | 4 |
| May | 5 |
| June | 6 |

The rolling `AVG` for the first 4 months (J, F, M, A) will be: 2.5.

The rolling `AVG` for the second 4 months (F, M, A, M) will be: 3.5.

The rolling `AVG` for the third 4 months (M, A, M, J) will be: 4.5

Hope I helped you to understand the situation better.

My answers:

- If you see "rolling" then that is a typical use case of `window functions`. I don't know the reason why you need a "double AVG" usage.
- `OVER` represents that we are talking about a `window function`. We need to add it, this is how it works.
- Maybe with some sub-queries, but I don't think that is a good approach.

Best!